# Gmail > Google App Script > Gsheet > Slack Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, webhooks, slack

I'm having a bit of a formatting issue. I use this program to track my purchase orders and I have it set up to send me all of the purchases orders placed each day, and the email looks like this:
[image]

And then I set up a google sheet with the following code to pull the email into the sheet:

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:inbox is:unread from:[SERVER EMAIL]";

    function getEmails_(q) {
        var emails = [];
        var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
        for (var i in threads) {
            var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
            for (var j in msgs) {
                emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                    .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
                ]);
            }
        }
        return emails;
    }

    function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
        sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
    }

    function saveEmails() {
        var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
        if (array2d) {
            appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly for importing the data, but unfortunately it all into A2 cell, and looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get this to be formatted more like the grid in the email? When I push it into slack it has no formatting capabilities because it is all in one cell. Here is the code I use to push this into Slack:

```
function triggerSlackRequestProgress(channel, msg) {
 var slackWebhook = "[SLACK WEBHOOK]";
  var payload = { "channel": channel, "text": msg, "link_names": 1, "username": "Email Test", "icon_emoji": ":cowboykeen:" };
 var options = { "method": "post", "contentType": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) };

Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebhook, options));
}

function notifySlackChannelOfProgress() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 if (!sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()) return;
var channel = getChannel();

var msg = createProgressMessage(sheet);
 triggerSlackRequestProgress(channel, msg);
}

function isTest() {
 return false;
}

function getChannel() {
 if(isTest()) {
 return "[SLACK CHANNEL]";
 } else {
 return "[SLACK CHANNEL]";
 }
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

But what I would prefer is to be able to edit it more to look like this. Where the Order Date, Requested By, Description, etc. are all in separate cells so I could format it:

[image]

Any help with his would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Tanaike Any ideas for this one? I really appreciated your help with my last question. Thanks!

Comment: In your script, ``array2d`` retrieved by ``getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY)`` is used for putting to spreadsheet. At this time, the values are put in one cell. I think that the solution of your issue is in ``getEmails_()``. But I cannot propose about the direct solution from your question, because of no data. So can you confirm about this and modify the script? I'm really sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you! No need to apologize, I really appreciate all the help I can get! Would it help if I posted the google sheet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to convert the values of spreadsheet to the correct position, a sample spreadsheet is required. If you want to directly put the values from email to the correct position of spreadsheet, the email values are required. But I think that because the email data includes the personal information, about this, I cannot decide.

Comment: @Tanaike Hereis the link: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tOldE6h1vF4405tPfwNO5gtXABUHLEaFOmnifsLv4Hk/edit?usp=sharing) I guess either way would work. It would probably be cleaner long run if it was imported into the google sheet in the correct formatting, but if thats not possible then having it autoformat once in the sheet would work too. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot access to the shared spreadsheet. Could you please confirm it?